# CDC control task error "There is no change data for this table" in SSIS

Tags: ssis, cdc

When I try to run the SSIS task "CDC Control Task" with the operation "Get Processing Range" to begin an incremental load of data, I get the "There is no change data for this table" error.

[image]

I have CDC enabled on the table and everything works fine with SSIS and CDC on the initial load with the "Mark initial load start".

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJSvKgfXgtk&t=318s

Answer (score 4):

Turned out the SQL Server Agent was turned off and wasn't processing anything.  If your *[table_name]_CT* table (under 'System Tables') that probably means your Agent is off too.